# Tomcat no Windows e Linux

Tags: linux, windows, servidor, tomcat

Atualmente tenho um servidor `Tomcat` rodando em uma máquina com `Windows Server 2012`. Porém recebi algumas dicas de uns amigos de Infra onde os mesmos dizem que o `Tomcat` no `Linux` tem melhor performance. Então me surgiu essas dúvidas:

1. Qual os prós e contras ao utilizar `Tomcat` nessas plataformas?
2. Em qual das duas há maior desempenho?

Comment: Esse artigo em inglês pode lhe ajudar: http://www.webperformance.com/library/reports/windows_vs_linux_part2/

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2546/devemos-aceitar-perguntas-do-supt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. O pró de usar Windows Server é o suporte da Microsoft.
   Os prós de usar Linux são Segurança, Estabilidade, Preço (não tem que pagar licenças, e se forem hospedagem de terceiros o preço é menor também), Performance.
2. Como mostrado nos gráficos do artigo proposto pelo colega Giancarlo Abel Giulian, o Linux sai melhor no geral.